# IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null by requestLocationUpdate

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to create a dialog to configure the gps if this is off before starting LocationUpdates, but I have the following error. 
any solution?

This is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener locationListener;
Context context;
private TextView mLatLng;
DialogSettingsGPS dialogGPS;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //---use the LocationManager class to obtain locations data---
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLatLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_lng);
    dialogGPS = new DialogSettingsGPS(MainActivity.this);

    // getting GPS status
    isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(isGPSEnabled){
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();        
    }else{  
        dialogGPS.showSettingsAlert();      
    }

}


@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            10000, //mínimo tiempo de actualización
            0,  //mínima distancia de act.
            locationListener);  
}    

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    //---remove the location listener---
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
//Para escuchar los cambios el Location, se necesita crear una clase 
//que implemente la interfaz de LocationListener.

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
            mLatLng.setText(getString(R.string.latitude_longitude, latitude, longitude));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {          
    }
  } 

}
```

and this the class for the dialog, DialogSettingsGPS:

```
public class DialogSettingsGPS extends Service {

private final Context mContext;

public DialogSettingsGPS(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;

}


/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Configuración GPS");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS desactivado. ¿Desea ir al menu de configuración?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configuración", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

This is the error:

> 03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750): Process:
>   com.example.followtrackgps, PID: 6750 03-20 16:33:10.643:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume
>   activity
>   {com.example.followtrackgps/com.example.followtrackgps.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2826)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 03-20 16:33:10.643:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102) 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 03-20 16:33:10.643:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-20 16:33:10.643:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6750): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   invalid listener: null 03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):    at
>   android.location.LocationManager.checkListener(LocationManager.java:1635)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:450)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   com.example.followtrackgps.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:68)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5327) 03-20
>   16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
>   03-20 16:33:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):   ... 12 more

thanks in advance.

Comment: What would happen if `isGPSEnabled` is false. Hint: will `onResume()` be called?